# how to calculate drag force (to be used later in the calculation of drag coefficient)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design, aerodynamics, car

I'm working on a school project for car design (M segment car) we already found an open source Toyota model and can get the final answer online, but I want to know how can I calculate them

what's on my mind that I need to find drag force then use the equation to find the drag coefficient, however it's 2 unknown 1 equation

Comment: Not too sure what you are asking. Do you have a 3d model of the surfaces of the car and want to work out the CdA? That's really a job for CFD and is way beyond a school project.

Comment: actually i didn't want to use ansys "it's complicated and need time to learn"
so i was asking if there is an old method or way to find directly the drag and drag coefficient "of course without wind tunnel :D", by school i meant university

Comment: The old fashioned way was 1:5 scale models in a windtunnel, in my experience. That being said for simple shapes you can get a long way with hand calcs, but I don't think that applies to typical car body shapes in proximity to the ground. As an example the estimated Cd for the Aptera has increased to 0.11 from the early estimates of 0.06, ie 83% increase. Since this is a uni project then CFD is feasible. You could have a read of Hucho and see if there's a manual approach.

Comment: If you haven't got a wind tunnel, what about a water flume?  The lower kinematic viscosity of water as compared to air means you can do a valid scale model experiment (Reynolds number matching) at a smaller size scale and/or a lower speed than you'd need in a wind tunnel.

Comment: @GregLocock Consider a spherical car...